# scheme - sorting using accumulate

Tags: sorting, scheme, fold, accumulate

i want to write a procedure that gets an un-sorted list (might include duplicate values) and sort it using "accumulate" a.k.a foldr, reduce etc.

i succeeded in filtering double values but can not sort it. Generaly i cannot see how i can sort it using map, filter, accumulate ....

i have to accomplish it without using  insertion-sort , bubble sort ....

this is my code for now

(accumulate (lambda (x no-duplicate) (cons x (filter (lambda (z) (not (= x z))) no-duplicate))) '() (list 1 2 0 66 3 4 ))

Comment: just a note: reduce and accumulate are known as foldl - assembling the result at the same time as traversing the sequence from left...

Answer (score 3):

You can simply implement insertion-sort.

The accumulated value is a sorted list of all values seen so far.
When a new value is seen, it is inserted into the sorted list
at the right place. Use the same `insert` for this, as you
would in an ordinary implementation of insert-sort.

What you must write is a function `insert` that given an element `x` and a sorted list `ys` return a sorted list containing both x and all elements in `ys`. Use this function with accumulate, to build your end result of one element at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is [tree sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort), which is like insertion sort (@soegaard's solution) but with better time complexity. Here, you start with an empty tree as the initial value, and build the tree up at each fold iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @soegaards' answer: first define an insertion procedure that given an element, a comparison procedure and a list, returns a new list with the element in place according to the comparison procedure:

```
(define (insert-in-order e cmp lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (list e))
        ((cmp e (car lst))
         (cons e lst))
        (else
         (cons (car lst) (insert-in-order e cmp (cdr lst))))))
```

Now you can implement an insertion sort procedure in terms of `foldr` and `insert-in-order`, it receives as parameters the list to be sorted and a comparison procedure:

```
(define (insertion-sort lst cmp)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (insert-in-order e cmp acc))
         '()
         lst))
```

Use it like this:

```
(insertion-sort '(4 5 1 1 2 3) <) ; ascending order
> '(1 1 2 3 4 5)

(insertion-sort '(4 5 1 1 2 3) >) ; descending order
> '(5 4 3 2 1 1)
```